# How can I get the offset value in KStream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm developing a PoC with Kafka Streams. Now I need to get the offset value in the stream consumer and use it to generate a unique key `(topic-offset)->hash` for each message. The reason is: the producers are syslog and only few of them have IDs. I cannot generate a UUID in the consumer because in case of a reprocess I need to regenerate the same key.

My problem is: the `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext` class exposes an `.offset()` method that returns the value, but I'm using KStream instead of the Processor, and I couldn't find a method that returns the same thing.

Anybody knows how to extract the consumer value for each row from a KStream?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814437/how-to-filter-keys-and-value-with-a-processor-using-kafka-stream-dsl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use mix-and-match DSL and Processor API via `process(...)`, `transform(...)`, and `transformValues(...)`.

It allows you to access the current record offset similar to plain Processor API. In you case, it seems you want to use `KStream#transform(...)`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814437/how-to-filter-keys-and-value-with-a-processor-using-kafka-stream-dsl

Comment: Even with Processor API, we only have access to key and value and not to ConsumerRecord, only timestamp extractor seem to have ConsumerRecord. Can you please add additional details about accessing partitionId, timestamp, offset and other fields.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, Processor API provides a `ProcessorContext` object via `Processor#init(...)` method. `ProcessorContext` is updated before each call to `process()` with the metadata of the next record that will be processed. Thus, when `process()` gets called, you can get record offset etc by calling the corresponding `ProcessorContext` methods. Just keep a reference to it in  a class member variable that you initialize with the provided `ProcessorContext` in `init()`.

Comment: Thanks! ProcessorContext has everything needed.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax How can the latest offset be retrieved? I only find the current offset in the processor context

Comment: You mean the end offset of the input topics? There is no API in Kafka Streams for this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, apparently if one Kafka Streams application is assigned to multiple partitions which creates different tasks, the `ProcessorContext` might be assigned to different tasks and then `topic=null, partition=-1, orrset=-1`.

Did anyone encountered this?

---

Edit: the reason of that is that I have broken `TransformerSupplier` API and returned same instance from it. Always creating new instance fixes the issue.