# How to log offset in KStreams Bean using spring-kafka and kafka-streams

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have referred almost all the questions regarding logging offset on KStreams via Processor API's transform() or process() method like mentioned in many questions here -

[How can I get the offset value in KStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807346/how-can-i-get-the-offset-value-in-kstream?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But Im not able to get the solution these answers so I'm asking this question.

I want to log the partition, consumer-group-id and offset each time the message is consumed by the stream, I'm not getting how to integrate process() or transform() method with the ProcessorContext API? And if I'm implementing Processor interface in my CustomParser class then I would have to implement all the methods but Im not sure if that will work, like it is mentioned in the confluent docs for Record Meta Data - https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#streams-developer-guide-processor-api

I've set up KStreams in a spring-boot application like below (for reference have change the variable names)

```
 @Bean
    public Set<KafkaStreams> myKStreamJson(StreamsBuilder profileBuilder) {
        Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);

        final KStream<String, JsonNode> pStream = myBuilder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));

        Properties props = streamsConfig.kStreamsConfigs().asProperties();
       

        pstream
                .map((key, value) -> {
                            try {
                                return CustomParser.parse(key, value);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LOGGER.error("Error occurred - " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                            return new KeyValue<>(null, null);
                        }
                )
                .filter((key, value) -> {
                    try {
                        return MessageFilter.filterNonNull(key, value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOGGER.error("Error occurred - " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .through(
                        outputTopic,
                        Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonPOJOSerde<>(TransformedMessage.class)));

        return Sets.newHashSet(
                new KafkaStreams(profileBuilder.build(), props)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `Transformer`; save off the `ProcessorContext` in `init()`; you can then access the record metadata in `transform()` and simply return the original key/value.

Here is an [example of a Transformer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/7dda5ecd1d4b844717a3379caeb4f8b1506fc61a/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/streams/messaging/MessagingTransformer.java#L63-L91). It is provided by Spring for Apache Kafka to invoke a Spring Integration flow to transform the key/value.

Comment: Thank you, added a CustomTransformer which logs the details and then returns the same key and value.